# Spring MVC file upload to project directory

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, file-upload

```
@Controller {
   String path = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath();
   System.out.println(path);
   D:\folder1\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\project-name\
   file.transferTo(new File(path+file.getOriginalFilename()));  
}
```

How to do upload to the actual project folder instead of the tmp0 folder for file upload?

Answer (score 1):

I would give the community project called [Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/) a try.  This project makes it very easy to handle files uploads/downloads/streaming and associating that content with Spring Data entities, should you want to.

Adding it would look something like this:

> pom.xml (assuming maven.  Spring boot starters also available)

```
    <!-- Java API -->
    <!-- just change this depdendency if you want to store somewhere else -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-content-fs</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.M3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- REST API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-content-rest</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.M3</version>
    </dependency>
```

> StoreConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableFilesystemStores
@Import(RestConfiguration.class)
public class StoreConfig {

    @Bean
    FileSystemResourceLoader fileSystemResourceLoader() throws IOException {
        return new FileSystemResourceLoader(new File("/path/to/uploaded/files").getAbsolutePath());
    }

}
```

> FileStore.java

```
  @StoreRestResource(path="files")
  public interface FileStore extends Store<String> {
  }
```

And that's it.  The FileStore is essentially a generic Spring ResourceLoader.  The `spring-content-fs`  dependency will cause Spring Content to inject a filesystem-based implementation.  The `spring-content-rest` dependency will cause Spring Content to also inject an implementation if an `@Controller` that forwards HTTP requests onto the methods of the `FileStore` service.

So you will now have a fully functional (POST, PUT, GET, DELETE) REST-based file service at `/files` that will use your `FileStore` to retrieve (and store) files in `/path/to/uploaded/files` on your jboss server.

So:

`curl -F 'data=@path/to/local/image.jpg'  /files/image.jpg`

will upload `image.jpg` and store it in `/path/to/uploaded/files` on your server.

And:

`curl /files/image.jpg`

would retrieve it again.

HTH